# Jquery Using JSON data, find all articles where ArrayContents exist as Child Nodes

Tags: jquery, json

First time writing so much script so I'm sure there are lots of places where it could be tightened up.

I get a JSON that looks like this

```
{
"totalCount": 52,
"pageIndex": 1,
"pageSize": 20,
"count": 20,
"articles": [{
    "id": "203612858",
    "title": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "body": "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "categories": [{
        "id": 10166,
        "name": "Royal Canadian Air Force ",
        "keywords": [{
            "id": 200002235,
            "hits": ["RCAF"]
        }, {
            "id": 200001982,
            "hits": ["NATO"]            
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 10173,
        "name": "NATO",
        "keywords": [{
            "id": 200002235,
            "hits": ["RCAF"]
        }, {
            "id": 200001982,
            "hits": ["NATO"]
        }, {
            "id": 200002161,
            "hits": ["SUPER HORNET", "SUPER HORNETS"]   
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 10170,
        "name": "Procurement",
        "keywords": [{
            "id": 200002235,
            "hits": ["RCAF"]
        }, {
            "id": 200001982,
            "hits": ["NATO"]            
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 10165,
        "name": "Canadian Army",
        "keywords": [{
            "id": 200002235,
            "hits": ["RCAF"]
        }, {
            "id": 200001982,
            "hits": ["NATO"]            
        }]
    }],
    "publication": {
        "id": 213,
        "name": "xxxxx"
    },
    "publicationDate": "2016-12-02T10:55:11Z",
    "media": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "RSS Feed"
    },
    "articleUrl": "http://xxx"
}
```

What I need to do, in this case is return any Articles in which the Categories node contains AT LEAST all the IDs I have searched for, which are in an Array.  So if I search for 2 categories and only 1 match, I don't want it but if the 2 categories match and there are others, that's fine, the Article is pushed to a new Array which I will return to the user.

Hopefully there's a much better way of doing this.

Here's the code I'm using to call the script (removed some lines for brevity)

```
var Categories = ["F10167", "F10182" ];
displayContent('BreakingNews', Categories, "and");
```

my .js

```
function displayContent(tag, cat, and)
{
    $.getJSON(url, function(result){
    //Hold ALL my Articles
        myjson = result.articles;

$.getJSON(url, function(result){
    //Hold ALL my Articles
    myjson = result.articles;

    //If someone used the AND Switch
    if(and !== null)
    {   
    var length = cleanedCategories.length;

    $.each(myjson, function(i, article){
    //Find the Categories Collection inside each article
    var categories = article.categories;
    //Check if there is more than 1 category, if not skip
    if(categories.length > 1)
    {
    $.each(categories, function(i, c){

    for ( var x = 0 ;  x < length; x++ ) {
           //The below line always appear to return -1 even though I can see
           //the corresponding ID being compared 
       if(jQuery.inArray(parseInt(cleanedCategories[x]),parseInt(c.id)) !== -1) {
           newjson.push(article);   
        }                   
    }   
    });     

    }});                                                                            }
    else
    {
    newjson = myjson;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you could use linq.js library, to work like lambda. https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: I had no idea this existed! I love linq!  Hopefully this will do what I need, thank you!